# Modifying the value of a Mono and forming a different object

Tags: spring, mono, reactive

I have a service that returns a Mono. In my controller, when I get the Mono, I would like to modify the A to another object B and return B.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Mono.map()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) function can be used for modifying the item emitted by the Mono.

Example:

```
Mono<A> aMono = Mono.just(new A());
Mono<B> bMono = aMono.map(a -> {
    B b = new B();
    b.setS(a.getS());
    return b;
});
```